# Window not displaying SDL2

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 for the first time, and when I try to create a window, it's not displaying. The only sight of the window is an icon spawning in my dock ([Image of the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFCci.png), SDLTest.out is the name of my executable file). I found out that it spawned when `SDL_INIT()`was called.

I tried updating the window, changing its color and adding the flag `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN`, but none of these solutions worked. I even pasted a code from the Internet, but it didn't work better.

Here is the code that I pasted:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    int status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    SDL_Color orange = {255, 127, 40, 255};
    
    if(0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_Init : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(NULL == window)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_CreateWindow : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if(NULL == renderer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_CreateRenderer : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }
    
    if(0 != SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, orange.r, orange.g, orange.b, orange.a))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_SetRenderDrawColor : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }
    
    if(0 != SDL_RenderClear(renderer))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_SetRenderDrawColor : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }
    
    SDL_Delay(500);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(500);
    
    status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

Quit:
    if(NULL != renderer)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    if(NULL != window)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return status;
}
```

My OS is MacOS 11.6, my compiler GCC, my computer has a graphic card Intel Iris Pro Graphics 6200, and I installed SDL2 using Homebrew.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I tested your code in my Linux, and it work: an empty window is shown, then it is filled orange, and then it closes.

Comment: This is what it is supposed to do, but this doesn't work on my computer ;(

Comment: You need an event loop. Stuff doesn't work without one on some platforms. Continue reading your tutorial, it should be there somewhere.

Comment: It worked properly, thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just needed an event loop. I added this code and it worked:

```
    SDL_bool quit = SDL_FALSE;
    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            quit = SDL_TRUE;
    }
```

Thank you to HolyBlackCat for your comment!